# QOS on Linksys E900

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ping, qos

**Intro:** I live in Brazil, here I have a 2MB internet connection. When someone else is watching a video on Youtube or Netflix, I can't play anything, the ping oscillates so much. I can't play any online game, eg: League of Legends, Counter Strike or even slither.io.

**Question:** Is there any way to configure my Linksys E900 QOS to solve this problem, I mean, by prioritizing games without blocking the video that is playing.

Comment: You can prioritize outgoing traffic, but not really do much about incoming traffic. The bandwidth has already been used by the time you see incoming traffic.

Comment: @RonMaupin So, there's nothing that I can do about it?

Comment: Ask the other users to stop while you play a game, make a schedule when each user has a time to use the internet for high bandwidth stuff like movies and youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Latency problems on home Internet connections usually aren't due to a lack of priority, they're usually due to crappy modems/routers/gateways/APs that, in a misguided effort to never drop a packet, allow their buffer queues to become bloated and stay bloated, which does a double-whammy of adding latency while at the same time breaking TCP's congestion control algorithms.

The solution is to run a router that does Smart Queueing, which is an advanced form of Active Queue Management. The two most well-respected Smart Queuing algorithms are CoDel and PIE. Routers that implement these won't let their buffer queues get bloated. They will do Explicit Congestion Notification on packets as congestion becomes a problem, and they will be smart about dropping packets if ECN isn't enough. This allows TCP Congestion Control to work.

Luckily, there is aftermarket firmware for your E900, such as DD-WRT and OpenWrt, that support CoDel.

For more information, see [bufferbloat.net](http://www.bufferbloat.net/).